# Retrieving token from persisted store on app initialization React Native, Redux-Persist

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I have plugged in redux-persist in my application. When the app is relaunched after it was killed, the first think Id like to do is to get my auth token in the rehydrated store and check if the token is still valid.

I am struggling to find the good strategy to do that. As a first intuition I would try to do that in the root App component in the componentDidMount method. Here's my component :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('in app componentDidmount')
    console.log(store.getState())
    console.log(persistor.getState())
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <Router />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

However `store.getState()` gives me the non rehydrated state and `persistor.getState()` gives me a non usable object:

```
{ bootstrapped: false, registry: ["root"] }
```

Here's also my `store.js` file :

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2, // see "Merge Process" section for details.
  blacklist: ['error', 'loading', 'backgroundImage'],
};
const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export const store = createStore(pReducer, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)));

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

## Method 1

Do it in the callback of `persistStore`:

```
export const persistor = persistStore(store, null, () => {
  console.log('state', store.getState());
});
```

### Method 2

Do it in `componentDidMount` of a component that is nested within `PersistGate`:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(store.getState());
  }
  render() {
    return <Router />;
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <Main />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: I am already using persistgate, and what i get in componentDidMount is the non rehydrated state

Answer (score 0):

I let you here a link to a Medium article that explains exactly what you want to build.

I can't help you at the moment cause I'd need more fragments of your code since it works with Redux.

Hope this article helps you: https://medium.com/@alexmngn/the-essenSharryUptial-boilerplate-to-authSharryUpenticate-users-on-your-react-native-app-f7a8e0e04a42